# Find the range of the function $f(x)=-1/|1-x|$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

My procedure: Let $f(x)=y$.
$$|1-x|=-1/y$$
But,
$$|1-x|>0$$
so,
$$-1/y>0$$
Then, what will I do? And what is the answer?

Comment: What is the domain, $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$?

Comment: Hint: What is the range of $|1-x|$?

Comment: Multiply both sides by $-y^2$ which gives you $y<0$.

Answer (score 4):

Range is $y < 0$ since $y$ can't be zero and $|1-x|$ is non negative.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = -\frac{1}{|1-x|}$ for all x i.e domain being (R$-${1}) as it is discontinuous at $x=1$.

Case 1 : $1-x>0$ $\implies$ $x<1$ i.e the domain is $(-∞,1)$. Now $f(x) = \frac{1}{x-1}$, here as $x \to 1^-$ , $f(x)\to-∞$ and as $x\to-∞$ , $f(x) \to 0$. Summarizing we can say that for domain $(-∞,1)$ the range corresponds to $(-∞,0)$.

Case 1 : $1-x<0$ $\implies$ $x>1$ i.e the domain is $(1,∞)$. Now $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$, here as $x\to1^+$ , $f(x) \to -∞$ and as $x\to∞$ , $f(x) \to 0$. Summarizing we can say that for domain $(1,∞)$ the range corresponds to $(-∞,0)$.

Overall range is $(-∞,0)$ for the complete real line with a discontinuity at $x=1$.

Comment: The domain cannot be the complete real line since the function is undefined when $x = 1$.

Comment: Formatting tips:  typing `$\implies$` yields $\implies$; typing `$\to$` yields $\to$.  For more information on typing mathematics on this website, see this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Welcome to MathSE.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you for the formatting tips.

Comment: Yess I wrote in the first line that domain is the real line, but while solving in both the cases 1 is not included in the domain, its in the open braces.

Answer (score 0):

Try to sketch graph you will get more clarity $f(x) = -\frac{1}{|1-x|}$  you will see range is $(-∞,0)$ for the complete real line with a discontinuity at $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Begin with the following consider $f(x)$ as composition of $|1-x|$ then $1/x$ then $-x$ the first maps $R$ onto the positive $R^+\cup\{0\}$ the second maps the resulting set to itself finally the last one will flip so it maps it to $R^-\cup \{0\}$ I consider the extended real without considering that the result is $(-\infty,0)$